# Is it possible to extract eigenvalues from PCA estimator from sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca, covariance, eigenvalue

After I fit some data with PCA:

```
estimator = PCA(n_components)
estimator.fit(mydat)
```

can I obtain eigenvalues of covariance matrix, which were computed inside (and which IMO are equal to variances of projected data)?

Comment: did you check the [attributes](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) in the function documentation? Would the singular values suffice?

Comment: Here https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/134283/42357 it is said, that principal values are not the same as eigenvalues

Comment: yes, but you can derive them via $\lambda_j = s_j^2/ (n-1)$

Answer (score 0):

The eigenvalues should be in:

```
estimator.explained_variance_
```

If you compare it with another software, do not forget to standardize the data first:

```
import sklearn.preprocessing
mydat = sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit_transform(mydat_before_std)
```

Then you should have results close to what R would give you.